# How can create table contains this result?

Tags: php

I have this result I want to parse and get Lfam for example  in following my result  :

```
> > > object(stdClass)[159]
> >       public 'PapFamType' => 
> >         array (size=28)
> >           0 => 
> >             object(stdClass)[164]
> >               public 'Owner' => string '' (length=0)
> >               public 'Fam' => string 'CMM' (length=3)
> >               public 'Lfam' => string 'CouchÃ© moderne
> 
> mat' (length=19)
>               public 'Ctype' => string 'CM5' (length=3)
>               public 'Ltype' => string 'Chromomat' (length=9)
>               public 'Ccoul' => string 'BC' (length=2)
>               public 'Lcoul' => string 'BLANC' (length=5)
>               public 'Gramm' => string '400' (length=3)
>               public 'PoidsM' => string '0' (length=1)
>              
>           1 => 
>             object(stdClass)[165]
>               public 'Owner' => string '' (length=0)
>               public 'Fam' => string 'CMM' (length=3)
>               public 'Lfam' => string 'CouchÃ© Moderne Mat' (length=19)
>               public 'Ctype' => string 'CM5' (length=3)
>               public 'Ltype' => string 'Chromomat' (length=9)
>               public 'Ccoul' => string 'IV' (length=2)
>               public 'Lcoul' => string 'IVOIRE NATUREL' (length=14)
>               public 'Gramm' => string '250' (length=3)
>               public 'PoidsM' => string '0' (length=1)
```

How I can parse this result ?

I searched, but I didn't found out how I could do it.
How can i put the result in table

```
oreach($GetJobResult->Components->Component as $component_index=>$component) {
                $quote_title= ($component_index+1).') '.$component->Title."\n";
                //var_dump($component_index+1);
                //die();

                if(isset($component->Paper->Family)) {
                    if(isset($component->Paper->Type) && isset($component->Paper->Color)) {


                        $getPaperInfoResult=$ws->getPaperInfo($component->Paper->Family,$component->Paper->Type);

                        $quote_desc = $getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]->Lfam.' - '.$getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]->Lcoul.' - '.$getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType[$component_index+1]-> Gramm.' g/m2'."\n";
                        var_dump($quote_desc); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with XML and SimpleXML? I see only a plain PHP object here.

Answer (score 0):

PapFamType is array of objects

```
<?php
foreach ($getPaperInfoResult->PapFamType as $papFamType) {
    foreach ($papFamType as $attr => $value) {
        // Attr Owner => value:
        // Attr Fam => value: CMM
        echo sprintf('Attr %s => value: %s', $attr, $value);
    }
}
```